# C# e.RowIndex ArgumentOutOfRangeException in Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

Why i'm getting this problem? 'ArgumentOutOfRangeException' was unhandled' in line #5.

- An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
- Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. The error points to [e.RowIndex]

  ```
    private void Sett_icts_DGV_prodAssign_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
           string prodid;
           int prodid1;
        {
            prodid = Sett_icts_DGV_prodAssign.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["prodassignid"].Value.ToString();

            if (prodid == "")
            {

                prodid1 = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                prodid1 = Convert.ToInt32(Sett_icts_DGV_prodAssign.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["prodassignid"].Value.ToString());
            }

            if (prodid1 == 0)

            {
                conn2.Open();
                string query601A = "INSERT INTO ihsasprodassign(prodassigndesc, prodassignkey, prodassigndte, prodassigntme, prodassignstat) VALUES('" + Sett_icts_DGV_prodAssign.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["prodassigndesc"].Value.ToString() + "' , '" + Convert.ToInt32(Sett_icts_DGV_prodAssign.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["prodassignkey"].Value.ToString()) + "' , '" + DateTime.Now + "','" + DateTime.Now + "', 'A')";
                cmda = conn2.CreateCommand();
                cmda.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmda.CommandText = query601A;
                cmda.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn2.Close();

            }
            else
            {
                conn2.Open();
                string query601B = "UPDATE ihsasprodassign set prodassigndesc='" + Sett_icts_DGV_prodAssign.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["prodassigndesc"].Value.ToString() + "', prodassignkey='" + Convert.ToInt32(Sett_icts_DGV_prodAssign.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["prodassignkey"].Value.ToString()) + "',prodassignmod='" + DateTime.Now + "' WHERE prodassignid=" + prodid1 + "";
                cmda = conn2.CreateCommand();
                cmda.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmda.CommandText = query601B;
                cmda.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn2.Close();      

            }

        }
  ```

Comment: Your issue seems to be: `Sett_icts_DGV_prodAssign.Rows[e.RowIndex]`. Either `Rows` is empty or `e.RowIndex` is below `0` or greater than the `Rows` property in which it can't. I would check the `e.RowIndex` first to make sure it's indeed not a negative number and or it's not more than `Sett_icts_DGV_prodAssign.Rows` before trying to access that index for that row.

Comment: another problem though is i can't initialize my fill grid function to populate the Sett_icts_DGV_prodAssign datagridview first then call this CellValueChanged method.  The whole code is inside a custom control and is triggered upon clicking by button in a mainform.

Comment: The posted code is malformed and will not compile. What are the two variable definitions doing BEFORE the first open brace “{“…?  `string prodid;` and `int prodid1;` should be AFTER the open brace and will cause a compile time error in its current form. In addition, I am pretty sure that `e.RowIndex` will NEVER be an invalid index considering this is coming from the grids `CellValueChanged` event. It is not possible to “change” a cells value that is “out of range” so I question the error in the first place. Please update your question with code that demonstrates this “out-of-bounds” error.